# find and replace all xml elements within a tag

Tags: xml, notepad++

I am editing an xml file in notepad++ and was wondering if it is possible to find and replace elements within specific tags. The reason I ask this is I am editing a lectora document and want to change the x and y coordinates on text boxes but only on certain chapters and if I do a find and replace for something  it will find and replace all instances of it for the whole document and I only need for a specific chapter/tag. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
<chapter id="46" parent="1">
<name>changing</name>

<point>
<x>65</x>
<y>90</y>
</point>

</chapter>

<chapter id="48" parent="1">
<name>nonchanging</name>
<point>
<x>65</x>
<y>90</y>
</point>

</chapter>
```

Comment: It can be done, but first - could you provide a sample of your XML and show which elements you need to replace along with the rules that qualify them for replacing?

Comment: Hi thanks for the the reply basically I would like to find and replace all instances of the x values in the tag with a chapter id of 46 without it affecting the x values in chapter id 48.I have added a sample of the XML above.

Comment: It feels like this would be easier using xpath

Comment: How do you do that, @Luis?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

Find what:

```
(<chapter id="(?!46).+<x>)(\d+)(</x>.+</chapter>)
```

Replace with:

```
\1YOURNUMBER\3
```

Also tick ". matches newline" checkbox.

But beware that this is not a good solution, and rather use it only in some ad-hoc work, where you can verify the results. 
As Luis suggested, xPath is the way to go for this kind of things.